# Out of gas while using transfer function

Tags: gas, address.transfer

I simply want the transaction to occur in integral ethers. I wish to refund the balance amount. I am using the following function in my contract for that. I am getting out of gas while running this function. I have increased the gas limit to 1 ether but to no avail.

```
function() payable {
    uint refund_amt = (msg.value % 1000000000000000000);
    tokens[msg.sender] += (msg.value - refund_amt) / 1000000000000000000;
    if (refund_amt != 0) msg.sender.transfer(refund_amt);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75679/discussion-on-question-by-ultimate-weapon-out-of-gas-while-using-transfer-functi).